# Magento2 : Product not saving set custom attribute using Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, discount, save

I want to **set Discount on my product after Save product** so I'm using **catalog_product_save_after** then I am  creating an **attribute 'discount' and set the calculated value, but when i save the collection it not working properly** ('stuck & looping admin panel loader'). How can i solve this issue ?

```
namespace Wac\SortDiscount\Observer\Catalog;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class ProductSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $orgprice = $product->getPrice();
        $specialprice = $product->getSpecialPrice();
        $product->setDiscount($orgprice - $specialprice);
        // die($specialprice);
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've saved the custom attribute value to the product with the below code.

```
class FilterProduct implements ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\ConfigurableFactory
     */
    protected $configurableProductProductTypeConfigurableFactory;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\ConfigurableFactory $configurableProductProductTypeConfigurableFactory
    ) {
        $this->configurableProductProductTypeConfigurableFactory = $configurableProductProductTypeConfigurableFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $productTypeId = $product->getTypeId();
        if (in_array($productTypeId, array("configurable", "grouped", "bundle"))) {
            if ($productTypeId == "configurable") {
                $skus = array();
                $childProducts = $this->configurableProductProductTypeConfigurableFactory->create()->getUsedProducts($product);
                foreach ($childProducts as $child) {
                    $skus[] = $child->getSku();
                }
                $skus = implode(', ', $skus);
                $product->setChildSku($skus);
                $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'child_sku');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You need to change your code from

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $orgprice = $product->getPrice();
        $specialprice = $product->getSpecialPrice();
        $product->setDiscount($orgprice - $specialprice);
        $product->save();
    }
```

To this

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $orgprice = $product->getPrice();
        $specialprice = $product->getSpecialPrice();
        $product->setDiscount($orgprice - $specialprice);
        $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'discount');
    }
```

Hope this will help!!!

Comment: same issue...! stuck the loader

Comment: I've added the code which I've used to update the custom attribute value for your reference. Hope this will help you to find the solution.

Comment: its working great .....! thanks dude ; )

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @Sumith please answer this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/289872/80389